# word problem concerning speed

Tags: recreational-mathematics, word-problem

> A man rows across a river 1/2 mi. wide and lands at a point 1/4 mi.
>   farther down the river. If the banks of the river are parallel
>   straight lines and he takes 1/2 h. to cross, what is his average speed
>   in feet per minute if his course is a straight line?

I found 88 ft/min

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: It's asking for the average speed.

Comment: Yes, but what is $\textit{your}$ question? Do you just want somebody to check your answer?

Comment: Yeah this is what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a right triangle having legs $1/2~\mathrm{mile}$ & $1/4~\mathrm{mile}$ then the man will follow the straight line path along the hypotenuse given as $$=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt 5}{4}\ ~\mathrm{miles}=\frac{5280\sqrt 5}{4}=1320\sqrt 5\ ~\mathrm{ft}$$
hence, the average speed of the man $$=\frac{\text{distance traveled}}{\text{time taken}}=\frac{1320\sqrt 5~\mathrm{ft}}{30~\mathrm{min}}=\color{red}{44\sqrt 5\approx 98.387 ~\mathrm{ft/min}}$$

Comment: You are right, thank yoU!